# How to rotate a rectangle within a \foreach loop?

Tags: tikz-pgf, rotating, foreach

Using this code :

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\newcounter{coreRot}\setcounter{coreRot}{45}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=5]
\foreach \x in {0,1,...,7}
\foreach \y in {0,1,...,7}
{
\draw [rotate=\arabic{coreRot},draw,fill] (\x mm,\y mm)  rectangle ++(.5mm,.2mm){};
\addtocounter{coreRot}{90};
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I get this image:

[image]

but I want an image like this:

[image]

How do I get horizontal rows and a rotation of the rectangle after each step in horizontal and vertical direction? How to rotate a rectangle within a \foreach loop after each step?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can start with something like this

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article} 
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}    
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[cyan] (0,0) grid (7,7);
        
        \foreach \y in {0,...,7}
            \foreach \x in {0,...,7}
                \node[rotate=45+\x*90+\y*90,rectangle,minimum width=5mm,minimum height=2mm,inner sep=0pt,fill=violet] at (\x,\y) {};

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: rotating pattern]

Comment: Note that I used `rectangle` where you can also use `ellipse` or even `diamond` (if you add `\usetikzlibrary{shapes}` in your preamble), which makes something nice too ;)   Here, you can delete it without changing the result.

Comment: Thanks a lot! By the way, [rotate=45+\x*90+\y*90, does the same. Rotate seems to accept 1260 degrees.

Comment: Ahaha, yes, 2*45=90, you're right. It's because I was searching for the correct setting and I didn't see that ;) Don't hesitate to accept the answer if it suits you.